ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _spropack: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable
Sorry about the bad English and programmation language, I'm kind of new to this. Anyway, here's my problem.
I have Spyder (Python 3.9) and I'd like to read some modules in my code. These modules need some scipy dependencies, and I always have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\users\arono\documents\gembloux\systèmes énergétiques et énergies renouvelables\tp3 batterie\main_v2.py:30
    from MODULES.ENVIRONMENT.light import Sun_positions, Light

File ~\Documents\Gembloux\Systèmes énergétiques et énergies renouvelables\TP3 batterie\MODULES\ENVIRONMENT\light.py:12
    import pvlib.solarposition as pvlibSP

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\pvlib\__init__.py:3
    from pvlib import (  # noqa: F401

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\pvlib\spectrum\__init__.py:2
    from pvlib.spectrum.mismatch import (  # noqa: F401

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\pvlib\spectrum\mismatch.py:8
    from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py:167
    from ._interpolate import *

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_interpolate.py:10
    import scipy.special as spec

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py:790
    from . import _orthogonal

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\_orthogonal.py:81
    from scipy import linalg

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py:134 in __getattr__
    return _importlib.import_module(f'scipy.{name}')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127 in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py:222
    from ._sketches import *

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_sketches.py:9
    from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py:308
    from . import csgraph

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.py:185
    from ._laplacian import laplacian

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_laplacian.py:7
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py:132
    from ._eigen import *

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_eigen\__init__.py:11
    from ._svds import svds

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_eigen\_svds.py:9
    from scipy.sparse.linalg._svdp import _svdp

File ~\anaconda3\envs\energie\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_svdp.py:24

from ._propack import _spropack  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _spropack: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.

I installed scipy with anaconda. I think I installed it with pip too, I mean I tried to (un)install it in Spyder.
Sorry if my question lacks information, this is new to me and I don't understand everything. Thanks for your help.
I'm ashamed to say I used ChatGPT, and it told me to (un)install it or upgrade it with pip or conda. I tried my best, restarted the kernel, but the problem is still the same.

Can you post a full traceback of one of these errors? Do you get this error if you run import scipy?

I added the traceback error in my post. And I don't get the error when I run 'import scipy'.

Can you see if your virus scanner quarantined any of SciPy's files?

Okay, I think I found the problem. I switched 'anaconda' environment and installed pvlib on it and it worked. But no idea why it didn't work on the original environment.

I solved a similar problem by updating scipy to the latest version in anaconda (both in the specific environment I use and the base environment).
